# How to "fully" delete a Department from the Azure EA Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-enterprise-administrator

I've deleted the old department, and its status is "Deleted", but it still appears in the portal. I know I can check the "Active" box and it disappears, but whenever I go back through the Department link, it reappears because the URL gets the `&all_d` appended, i.e.:

```
https://ea.azure.com/manage/department?enrollmentId=XXXX&departmentId=YYY&all_d
```

So how can I permanently delete the old department?

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this same issue at my business site - I ended up calling support and they could remove it for me. You should have a dedicated account manager that will help you expedite this request.

It happened only once in my case, but that's all I have to go on in trying to
help you out here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fully delete a department once created.  You can edit the name but if you delete, it will just change to an inactive status so you can hide it from view.  The reason for not allowing deletion is in case there is historic usage associated with it where department would be listed in historic reporting.